# What is .NET string structure and how .NET take care to store and retrieve it's string structure?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Let's face following code :

```
string a = "This is not a long string!";
string b = "Another string";
b = "This is" + " not a long " + "string" + "!";
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); //True !
string c = "This is" + " not a long " + "string" + '!';
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(a, c)); //False
```

The only reason I see is that .NET has optimized variables to take less space.

Does .NET store strings with zero terminated[null] or string length ?
I mean when I write following code is it possible to lose the part after the null char if .NET run optimization against the string ?

```
string Waaaa = "This is not \0a long string!";
```

Comment: Are you asking these as an exercise in learning, or for a practical reason?  I ask because it doesn't seem to me that you should be asking such things practically - strings should "just work", and you should use any of the built-in comparison methods (e.g. `Equals`, `Compare`, `==`) rather than `ReferenceEquals` for any practical purpose.

Comment: Just for learning purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in .NET are in essence character arrays - `char[]` (where `char` is a representation of a UTF-16 character). They are not C strings - they are not null terminated.

What you see is the result of [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) - any string literal will get interned (and the compiler is smart enough to know to convert concatenated strings to a single literal).

Your `Waaaa` variable will be exactly what you have posted - with a null character in the middle.

Comment: thanks for your brilliant answer. Can you explain why compiler didn't detect string c is same as string a ?

Comment: @Mahdi _ I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: the distinct of all variables a,b,c is one string which compiler only know a is equal to b and don't know that a is also equal to c.

Comment: @Mahdi - I still have no idea what you mean. If you have these three variables set to the same string literal, the result will be a single string that all three variables point to.

Comment: Can you take a look at my first code ? object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) returns true while object.ReferenceEquals(a, c) returns false.

Comment: @Mahdi - The compiler is not smart enough to understand that concatenating a _character_ at the end will produce the same string as when concatenating strings.